# Making a Network Bridge does disconnect me from the internet

Tags: networking, bridge

I want to bridge 2 network connections one that is virtual (a vmware network connection) another one is the one that is connected to internet. When i select both and then make the bridge i will get disconnected from the internet. What is the reason? Any solution?

Comment: Can you post what OS you have?

Comment: What is is that you want to happen by bridging the connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to bridge the connections in Windows?  VMWare supports bridged connections itself, you just change the network connection in the virtual machine setup [from NAT to Bridged](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_configure_ws.html#1061905).

Answer (score 0):

Do what shf301 advised and make sure your NIC inside the virtual machine gets an IP address either dynamically or set it manually. Then you should have access to the Internet